# Is there a way to show OTP messages on screen without opening OTP messages?

Tags: sms

I am having problem switching between apps when using banking apps or online transaction on android phone when they sends OTP and I need to enter the OTP code.

**Sometimes when I switch to inbox to read and remember the OTP code, When I move back to the browser page to enter the OTP, the page gets reloaded and either it sends OTP again or triggers invalid page as the page gets reloaded.**

I need some way to show the OTP code on screen as soon as the message arrives in inbox so I can see and enter the code without switching between apps. Can someone help please?

Comment: Amit, multiple things here: first, asking for app recommendations is off-topic on Android.SE. But while this could be re-phrased into "how can I" in your case, it's the underlying issue to be aware of: ***You should not use the same device to receive OTP codes where you do the banking itself!*** That's a huge security risk. Hackers could intercept the code. Malware would have easy game this way. So a safe solution to your issue would rather involve using a second device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Multi Clipboard and OTP Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cv.copybubble). While this does Multi Copy or is a Clipboard manager, This also reads One time Passwords and show on a floating widget that actually resolves your issue.
Since you want to use OTP codes without switching to inbox, this app shows the OTP message in a floating widget and the code floats on screen as soon message arrives in your inbox.

**Note:** I'm affiliated with the company CV Infotech which has developed this app.

Answer (score 0):

Try FreeCharge app. It can detect OTP without opening messages. You can pay mobile bills, electricity bills, DTH and much more using this app.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using third party SMS manager apps like [SmartSMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smartsms.organizer.events)

It claims to have OTP Copy on notification shade, Moreover I've used this app so I guess it will be useful to you as well